# BadImage Exception in VS2017

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I am getting error while running the program at VS2017 [C#]. While I am running at my local system it is running fine. No error I am getting. But when I am build the solution and put the solution at the Prod server I am getting error. My mainlogin page is coming fine at prod server. But when I am trying to login using userid and password I am getting error.
What I have tried is a) at IIS I enable 32 bit b) Configure Any cpu at VS2017. but no luck.
Below is the error

```
BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsInit.CheckVersionCompatibility(String version) +0
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize() +388
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..cctor() +936
```

Please advice

Comment: Do you have references to DLLs in specific bitness?

Comment: This is not related to oracle, but a dependencies problem. Your program/application has probably a 64 bit referenced DLL and you try to run it on a 32 bit enviroment or viceversa

Comment: Correct you are.. I am referencing 64 bit DLL, but my production server is also 64 bit.